# Swift 4: Best way to change the length of an array?

Tags: swift

```
import Foundation

public
class Example001 {
    public
    func changeLength(of arrayOfInt: [Int], to newLength: Int) -> [Int] {
        let oldLength = arrayOfInt.count
        if oldLength == newLength {
            return arrayOfInt
        }

        if oldLength < newLength {
            var newArrayOfInt = [Int]()
            newArrayOfInt.append(contentsOf: arrayOfInt)
            for _ in oldLength ..< newLength {
                newArrayOfInt.append(0)
            }
            return newArrayOfInt
        }

        return Array(arrayOfInt.prefix(newLength))
    }
}
```

This method changeLength() returns an array based on an existing array and a new length.

The code works fine, whether the new array is shorter than, longer than, or the same length as the original array.

But I am wondering if there is some better way of doing this in Swift 4 in a more compact way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat swiftier version would be:

```
func changeLength(of arrayOfInt: [Int], to newLength: Int) -> [Int] {
    if newLength < arrayOfInt.count {
        return Array(arrayOfInt.prefix(newLength))
    } else if newLength == arrayOfInt.count {
        return arrayOfInt
    } else {
        return arrayOfInt + Array(repeating: 0, count: newLength - arrayOfInt.count)
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to go super-concise:

```
func changeLength(of arrayOfInt: [Int], to newLength: Int) -> [Int] {
    return Array(arrayOfInt.prefix(newLength)) + Array(repeating: 0, count: max(0, newLength - arrayOfInt.count))
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `... + repeatElement(0, count: ...)`